# How to use search/filter for HTML Divs generated from JSON data using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to add a filter for the links/divs generated from JSON data.

I already have a search filter working here without a problem IF the data isn't generated via JSON format. But I really need to use JSON for faster loading and processing.

The problem is, it fails to filter the links when doing so. It's supposed to filter divs based on the text inside `<a></a>` tags, including some hidden texts inside the `<span>`..

In this example, it can filter only the first item in the JSON, but not for the rest.

```js
// Links Filter
var input = document.getElementById("search-filter-cards");
input.addEventListener("input", searchFilterDivsMenu);

function searchFilterDivsMenu(e) {
  var filter = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
  var list = document.getElementById("links-list");
  var divs = list.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var a = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a) {
      if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        divs[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        divs[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

// JSON Data for each links
const maincards = {
  "linksList": [{
      'name': 'Java Bookmarks',
      'title': 'Java Bookmarks',
      'favicon': '../assets/links-favicons/java-bookmarks.png',
      'url': '#',
      'tags': 'Login, Logout, Log-in, Log in, Log-out Log out',
      'linkattributes': 'rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Chrono',
      'title': 'Chrono',
      'favicon': '../assets/links-favicons/chrono.ico',
      'url': '#',
      'tags': 'Login, Logout, Log-in, Log in, Log-out Log out',
      'linkattributes': 'rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Kanban (May)',
      'title': 'EDEN Kanban',
      'favicon': '../assets/links-favicons/kanban.ico',
      'url': '#',
      'tags': 'Login, Logout, Log-in, Log in, Log-out Log out, Kanban board',
      'linkattributes': 'rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"'
    },
  ]
};

const createMainCardLinks = ({
  name,
  title,
  favicon,
  url,
  tags,
  linkattributes
}) => `
    <div class="card link-container">
      <img class="link-img" src="${favicon}"/>
      <a class="link-title stretched-link" href="${url}" ${linkattributes} title="${title}">${name} <span class="h-0">${tags}</span></a>
    </div>
  `;

const links = maincards.linksList.map(createMainCardLinks);
links.forEach(links => {
  document.getElementById("load-json-data").innerHTML += links;
});
```

```css
.h-0 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input id="search-filter-cards" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type here to search">
  <div id="links-list">
    <div class="link-headers"><a class="mb-0">Sample Links</a></div>
    <div id="load-json-data"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm a beginner in JS and I couldn't figure out this problem for some time now. Anyways, thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me forever to notice your got ALL the divs in the links-list instead of load-json-data

Here is an improved version. It is simplified and because I only toggle the divs in load-json-data it works

```js
// Links Filter
var input = document.getElementById("search-filter-cards");
input.addEventListener("input", searchFilterDivsMenu);

function searchFilterDivsMenu(e) {
  const filter = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll("#links-list .card");
  cards.forEach(card => {
    var a = card.querySelector("a");
    // console.log(filter, "|", a.textContent.toUpperCase(), "|", a.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter))
    card.hidden = !a || (filter && a.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) === -1);
  })
}

// JSON Data for each links
const maincards = {
  "linksList": [{
      'name': 'Java Bookmarks',
      'title': 'Java Bookmarks',
      'favicon': '../assets/links-favicons/java-bookmarks.png',
      'url': '#',
      'tags': 'Login, Logout, Log-in, Log in, Log-out Log out',
      'linkattributes': 'rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Chrono',
      'title': 'Chrono',
      'favicon': '../assets/links-favicons/chrono.ico',
      'url': '#',
      'tags': 'Login, Logout, Log-in, Log in, Log-out Log out',
      'linkattributes': 'rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Kanban (May)',
      'title': 'EDEN Kanban',
      'favicon': '../assets/links-favicons/kanban.ico',
      'url': '#',
      'tags': 'Login, Logout, Log-in, Log in, Log-out Log out, Kanban board',
      'linkattributes': 'rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"'
    },
  ]
};

const createMainCardLinks = ({
  name,
  title,
  favicon,
  url,
  tags,
  linkattributes
}) => `
    <div class="card link-container">
      <img class="link-img" src="${favicon}"/>
      <a class="link-title stretched-link" href="${url}" ${linkattributes} title="${title}">${name} <span class="h-0">${tags}</span></a>
    </div>
  `;

const links = maincards.linksList.map(createMainCardLinks);
document.getElementById("load-json-data").innerHTML = links.join("")
```

```css
.h-0 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="search-filter-cards" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type here to search">
<div id="links-list">
  <div class="link-headers"><a class="mb-0">Sample Links</a></div>
  <div id="load-json-data"></div>
  <div class="card link-container">
    <img class="link-img" src="../assets/links-favicons/plus.ico" />
    <a class="link-title stretched-link" href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" title="Plus">Plus <span class="h-0">Quick Links</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="card link-container">
    <img class="link-img" src="../assets/links-favicons/google.ico" />
    <a class="link-title stretched-link" href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" title="Google">Google <span class="h-0">Quick Links</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh right! This is a really neat solution and is working! However, my concern is, I need to add a different set of links, so another variant of `<div id="load-json-data"></div>`, hence I'm really hoping to filter `<div id="links-list">`. Can you please tell me if this is possible? Anyways, I will look more into this and see if I can customise it. Thank you!

Comment: This is the first time I'm touching JSON data so I'm really unsure about a lot of things, so thank you so much for your help!

Comment: It looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vymzapfh/
In this demo, I just changed the HTML to add some more example divs below the `<div id="load-json-data"></div>`. When doing so, the filter won't work for those additional items.

Comment: Thank you and see you, I will keep trying until I get it hopefully.

Comment: Oh my goodness, it's working now by changing the selectors like you said! Thank you kindly!

Comment: See updated selector and HTML

Answer (score 1):

I have used jquery for appending, you can use javascript too.

```js
const dataJSON = {
  "linksList": [{
      'name': 'Java Bookmarks',
      'title': 'Java Bookmarks',
      'favicon': '../assets/links-favicons/java-bookmarks.png',
      'url': '#',
      'tags': 'Login, Logout, Log-in, Log in, Log-out Log out',
      'linkattributes': 'rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Chrono',
      'title': 'Chrono',
      'favicon': '../assets/links-favicons/chrono.ico',
      'url': '#',
      'tags': 'Login, Logout, Log-in, Log in, Log-out Log out',
      'linkattributes': 'rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Kanban (May)',
      'title': 'EDEN Kanban',
      'favicon': '../assets/links-favicons/kanban.ico',
      'url': '#',
      'tags': 'Login, Logout, Log-in, Log in, Log-out Log out, Kanban board',
      'linkattributes': 'rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"'
    },
  ]
};

dataJSON.linksList.forEach((element) => {
$('#myDiv').append(`
<div><a href="${element.url}"><img style="margin-right:10px;" src="${element.favicon}"/>${element.name}</a></div>
`);
})


function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, parentDiv, childDiv, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    parentDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    childDiv = parentDiv.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (i = 0; i < childDiv.length; i++) {
        a = childDiv[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            childDiv[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            childDiv[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myDiv {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myDiv div a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myDiv div a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<h2>Links Search</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<div id="myDiv">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this too is a really good sample. However I've been trying to change the `ul` and `li's` into `divs` like in my sample, but it doesn't seem to work. Can you please show me how to do if using divs?

Comment: I have edited the code with divs